# A Word To Represent The 5 Senses

Tags: single-word-requests, sense-verbs

Working on a game and I need a *single* word that represents the 5 senses: *smell*, *touch*, *taste*, *sound*, and *sight*.

At the moment I'm using "perception" which I don't think is adequate.

Comment: _Sensory perception_. ESP is something different.

Comment: a "SINGLE" word.

Comment: Too bad. You could hyphenate it.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about choosing the names of things in a program, which is on the explicit list of things that are specifically off-topic here.

Comment: what program? When did I say it was a program? It's a "story game".

Comment: Perception is perfect! You can perceive all those sensory experiences. It is also related to intellect, however. *Sensation* might also do. But if you want to make it more specific to the five senses, use "Sensory Perception" as Dr. Lawler suggested, even though it's two words.

Comment: It applies more to *the "things" perceived*, rather than the perception itself, but I think you could reasonably consider [qualia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualia) in this context.

Comment: **SENSES.**  Good Lord.

Comment: @Oldcat after some thought I think that would be the best term to use.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you considered [senses](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sense)?

> any of the faculties, as sight, hearing, smell, taste, or touch, by which humans and animals perceive stimuli originating from outside or inside the body.

It may be obvious, but I think it fits your needs nicely.

Comment: I kinda like the word you used "Stimuli", word that be appropriate?

Comment: No. Stimuli are things that activate, trigger, or are detected by, your senses.

Comment: I think Senses is the best word to use hear. I think I was just over complicating things.

Comment: I think "senses" is the best option for the OP, but note that we do have more senses then the five mentioned in the question, e.g., proprioception, sense of balance, etc.

Answer (score 4):

***Sensorium*** might be the word you want.

Definition of SENSORIUM

:  the parts of the brain or the mind concerned with the reception and interpretation of sensory stimuli; broadly :  the entire sensory apparatus

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sensorium

Comment: Good suggestion, but I'm not sure about this. In the game, this stats represents say your hearing, sight, etc. You have to consider cases where the stat goes down because you lose an eye, or damage your ear. Where Sensorium is brain oriented.

Answer (score 0):

Empiricism - Something you sense "empirically". (Pertaining to the 5 senses)

Comment: That's rather too far of a stretch for my taste.  (So to speak.)

Answer (score 0):

I am tossed between "sensable" and "sensate". The words are not universally defined in all the dictionaries but are there in some dictionaries.

Comment: Such as which dictionaries? Please include some references in your answer.

Answer (score -2):

I am thinking of the word stimuli.

However, a more suitable word is the ancient Greek word [αίσθηση](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B1%CE%AF%CF%83%CE%B8%CE%B7%CF%83%CE%B7) (aesthesee):
sensation, sense, perception, feeling, impression, notion.

The Greek for *five senses* is πέντε αισθήσεις (pente aestheseis).

This is the Greek word from which the English [aesthetic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/aesthetic) derives. Also spelled esthetic (US).

[Aesthetics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aesthetic) is a branch of philosophy involving indulging of senses to appreciate our environment.

I would not restrict the aesthetic senses, but if you need to you could coin the word *penthesys*, or *pentesthesys*.

Otherwise, in a computer game, one could have the basic aesthesis/aesthesys, and progressively gains further awareness or higher consciousness, gaining more talents of  aesthesys.

> aes·thet·ic or es·thet·ic  (s-thtk)
>   adj.
>
> 1. Relating to the philosophy or theories of aesthetics.
> 2. Of or concerning the appreciation of beauty or good taste: the aesthetic faculties.
> 3. Characterized by a heightened sensitivity to beauty.
> 4. Artistic: The play was an aesthetic success.
> 5. Informal Conforming to accepted notions of good taste.
>
> n.
>
> 1. A guiding principle in matters of artistic beauty and taste; artistic sensibility: "a generous Age of Aquarius aesthetic that said that everything was art" (William Wilson).
> 2. An underlying principle, a set of principles, or a view often manifested by outward appearances or style of behavior: "What troubled him was the squalor of [the colonel's] aesthetic" (Lewis H. Lapham).
>
> [German ästhetisch, from New Latin aesthticus, from Greek aisthtikos, of sense perception, from aisthta, perceptible things, from aisthanesthai, to perceive; see au- in Indo-European roots.]
>
> aes·theti·cal·ly adv.
>
> *The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fourth Edition copyright ©2000 by Houghton Mifflin Company. Updated in 2009. Published by Houghton Mifflin Company. All rights reserved.*